# Translating into rest frames of particles (general question with illustrative example)

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, particle-physics

Im trying to understand changes between frames.

Suppose that there is a collision between $e^{+}$ and $e^{-}$:

In the CM frame, the energy is $\sqrt{s}$ and in one scenario these $e^{+} + e^{-}$ could produce two tau ($\tau$) particles ($+$ and $-$)
That is: $$e^{+} + e^{-} \to \tau^{+} + \tau^{-}$$

Suppose also that there is a subsequent decay such that the $+\tau$ decays to 3 charged pions and a neutrino,
$$\tau^{+} \to \pi_{1} + \pi_{2} + \pi_{3} + \nu^{0}$$
and the $-\tau$ decays in a two-body decay.

Ignoring the neutrino we can present a "pseudo rest frame" for the $+\tau$.

**Ignoring the invisible part of the decay I want to translate the momentum of $-\tau$ decay products into the "pseudo $\tau$ - rest frame" and figure out the momentum of the outgoing visible particle in the other, $\tau$ - decay in this "rest frame".**

---

These are my thoughts so far:

So the tau + momentum could be written as $\vec{P_{\tau^{+}}} = P_{\pi, 1} +  P_{\pi, 2} + P_{\pi, 3}$  where $P_{\pi , n}$ are in the lab frame? Does that make sense?

Then I want the momentum of the visible particle in the - tau side in that particle's rest frame (or pseudo rest frame as we ignore the neutrino here).

Then $\vec{P_{\tau^{-}}}$ should be along a unit vector $\frac{-\vec{P_{\tau^{+}}}}{|P_{\tau^{+}}|}$, in the lab frame?

The energy of this tau - should be $\sqrt{s}/2$ in the tau rest frame, I think.

Taking the outgoing visible particle in the tau - side as having a momenutm in the lab frame of $\vec{P_{vis}} = (P_{vis,x},P_{vis,y},P_{vis,z})$ How would I translate that into this pseudo-rest frame?

My question is a general question with an example to help explain my thinking, how would one translate between the two frames. Answer with your own example if you'd prefer since perhaps mine is not clear

Comment: for particles , one has to use the fourvector algebra in order not to make mistakes when going to different rest frames http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/Relativ/vec4.html#c2

Comment: Sure, the four vector would be ($P_{vis,x}, P_{vis,y}, P_{vis,z},E_{vis})$ in the lab frame and what I want is the 4 vector in the rest frame. The energy is already known ($\sqrt{s}/2$) that is why I am focusing on the momentum part here.

Comment: I have edited your question to (hopeful) make your example clearer and more well-presented. It might be helpful bit if you could also clarify exactly what your general question is. Are you simply asking about the relevant equations for translating between the frames of 2 (special-) relativistic particles?

Comment: Note that if it is indeed this that you are asking, then the relation suggested by @annav is exactly what you are looking for